# Grails asset-pipeline: Reference a dependency's assets

Tags: asset-pipeline, grails-3.0

I'm building a grails app that uses assets from a dependency as if they were in my own project. Running the app in development mode works fine, as none of the files get uglified/minified. However, when the files are pre-processed for a production build there are errors because the processor can't find them.

You can see it in this output from the assetCompile task:

```
:assetCompile
...
Unable to Locate Asset: /spring-websocket.js
Unable to Locate Asset: /spring-websocket
Uglifying File 18 of 28 - application
Compressing File 18 of 28 - application
Processing File 19 of 28 - jquery-2.1.3.js
Uglifying File 19 of 28 - jquery-2.1.3
Compressing File 19 of 28 - jquery-2.1.3
Processing File 20 of 28 - my-websocket.js
Unable to Locate Asset: /spring-websocket
Uglifying File 20 of 28 - my-websocket
Compressing File 20 of 28 - my-websocket
...
Processing File 26 of 28 - sockjs.js
Uglifying File 26 of 28 - sockjs
Compressing File 26 of 28 - sockjs
Processing File 27 of 28 - spring-websocket.js
Unable to Locate Asset: /sockjs
Unable to Locate Asset: /stomp
Uglifying File 27 of 28 - spring-websocket
Compressing File 27 of 28 - spring-websocket
Processing File 28 of 28 - stomp.js
Uglifying File 28 of 28 - stomp
Compressing File 28 of 28 - stomp
Finished Precompiling Assets
```

The assets needed are bundled with spring-websocket (sock.js and stomp.js). You can see the precompiler complaining about them but then eventually finding them at the end. Those individual files make it into the final .war, but not into the minified application.js that has my dependent code in it. Does asset-pipeline have a way of dealing with this?

Comment: Seems to be a bug to me that is still there in Grails 4 - have reported it here: https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/issues/244